# Image not appearing as the set width in all screen

Tags: css

i am having an image element

```
<img className="Images_galley" src={imageGalley}  alt='Galley'/>
```

with the respective class as

```
.Images_galley{
  width:411%;
  height:auto;
  max-width: 980%;
}
```

for most 13" and 16" screens this works fine but in in between like 14" screen the image appears tiny and small is there a fix with css for this?